# Jquery edit inputvalue

Tags: jquery, input, edit, html

```
   $("#commands_table tr.nowrap").each(function(){

            var bevelnaam = $(this).find("input[id*='editInput']");
            var newname = "some text";
            var getthetr = bevelnaam.closest('tr').children(":first");
                            var editspan = getthetr.getElementById('edit');
                            var editinput = editspan.getElementsByTagName('input');
                            editinput[0].value = (newname);
                            editinput[1].click();        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tH9z6/4/

I'm trying to change the text (Aanval op Vlemis (507|434) C45) automatically. What I have above doens't seem to work however, and I don't know why. Any help? (Preferably in Jquery).

Comment: childeren => children

Comment: Edited, stull doens't work though :)

Comment: @user3227070 include your jQuery code in fiddle

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, in text, what it is you want to do? You're trying to loop through a couple of `tr` elements and change the span with id = `labelText[#]` in each of these? Do all spans get the same text?

Comment: Normally when you click on the image (http://cdn.tribalwars.nl/8.18/19348/graphic/rename.png?46239), it turns into an editable textbox, you can then change the text and click ok, and it will have changed. I'm trying to do that automatically, updating every matching element on the page with the new name I want to give it.

Comment: $(this).find("input[id*='editInput']"); => $(this).find("#editInput");

Comment: $(this).find("input[id*='editInput']");

This works and I need it to get my NewName (wich I have in code, but i's pretty long and not really relevant here).

Comment: @user3227070 Please show all your code if you want real help!

Comment: okay I will update it

Answer (score 0):

```
      var elketh = bevelnaam.closest('tr').children(":first");
                            $(elketh).find("input[id*='editInput']").val(nieuwenaam).next("input").click();
```